What is the fastest algorithm for generating all non-isomorphic unlabeled free trees for n-vertices, and also for caterpillar trees of n-vertices?
I'm aware of some algorithms for each problem such as the WROM algorithm for unlabeled free trees and the algorithm from this page for all caterpillar trees of n-vertices.
However, I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to this question.
